# Deploy and invoke multiple smart contract in one chaincode in javascript

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Does anyone know how I can deploy multiple smart contracts in javascripts in one chaincode and invoke all smart contracts with different files in CouchDB?

Comment: Can you end some more detail on exactly what you want to do?  Not sure what you mean by "different files in CouchDB".

Comment: Yes, can you please elaborate on that please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart contracts are essentially different functions within your chaincode file and you can have multiple smart contracts within the same chaincode. You have to create a class which extends the `Contract` class from `fabric-contract-api`, and define your functions inside. Finally, you need to export your class.
A simple example of this can be found here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript.

Invoking smart contracts can be done by using applications.
A javascript application example could be found here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript

Answer (score 0):

One chaincode install and instantiation would result into one database (I think this is what you meant by one file) within couch DB. All putState and getState would have the data put and got from this database within CouchDB. If a second chaincode is installed in the HLF network with a different name, then a new DB is created in CouchDB and all data put and got by this second chaincode would be from the second database. This is how HLF ensures that two chaincodes dont see each other's data as they are maintained separate to begin with.

Now, as said in above answer, each smart contract is a function in chaincode. You can author all of your API/ functions in one single chaincode, or start writing single chaincode for each function. This changes the number of databases created in your CouchDB by HLF, but it really depends on what you want to do.